# Stein and Shakarchi, Complex Analysis, Chapter 2 Example 2

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm reading through Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis textbook, but I'm a bit confused by their proof that
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

They consider the function $f(z) = \frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}$ and an indented semicircle as their contour[image]

The part where I'm confused is the integral of $f(z)$ over $\gamma_{\epsilon}^+$. The way they evaluate this integral is by first noting that
$$ f(z) = \frac{-iz}{z^2} + E(z) $$ where $E(z)$ is bounded as $z\rightarrow 0$. I'm fine with the rest of the proof but I'm puzzled by $E(z)$.

**My question:** How is this function bounded as $z \rightarrow 0$?

It seems like $E(z)$ would just be $$ E(z) = \frac{1+iz+e^{iz}}{z^2}$$

Is it *because* we're integrating over $\gamma_{\epsilon}^+$ and so $|z| = \epsilon$ and so

$$ \left| E(z) \right| = \left| \frac{1}{z} + \frac{i}{z} + \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} \right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{z} \right| + \left| \frac{i}{z} \right| + \left| \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2} \right| = \frac{1}{\epsilon} + \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} + \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} $$?

Comment: For $z \neq 0$, $f(z)+{iz \over z^2} = {1+iz - e^{iz} \over z^2} = \sum_{k=2}^\infty { i^k \over k!}z^{k-2}$, the latter is analytic everywhere.

Comment: @copper Sorry your comment beat my answer. It took me 5 minutes to find a } that should have been a ).

Comment: @TedShifrin :-) np at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,
\begin{align*}
E(z) &= \frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2} - \frac{-iz}{z^2} = \frac{1-\left(1+iz+\frac{(iz)^2}2 + \frac{(iz)^3}6 +\dots\right)}{z^2} - \frac{-iz}{z^2} \\ &= \frac{-\left(\frac{(iz)^2}2 + \frac{(iz)^3}6 +\dots\right)}{z^2} = \frac12 + O(z).
\end{align*}
It appears you lost a negative sign in writing down your formula for $E(z)$.